# Git: Your branch is ahead of 'upstream/master' by 2 commits

Tags: git, github

I have seen something like: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits`. But this time I am getting `upstream/master` instead of `origin/master`. Not able to get why?

```
abc@xyz MINGW64 /d/new (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'upstream/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Prior to this, I had updated my master (twice) via `git pull upstream master`, which surprisingly created a new commit for the update. I think that these two update commits are the 2 commits that the local master is "ahead of the upstream/master". But is there any specific reason/solution to this?

Now, If I merge my master to any branch, these 2 commits also become a part of the branch and of course, occur in my PR when I push it.

I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: This is normal if you've got two remotes (because e.g. your `origin` is a forked repo from your `upstream`). Is that the situation? What does `git remote` say?

Comment: Yes, my origin is indeed forked from the upstream.
But why does it creates a new commit when I update the master?

Comment: Well, you did a slightly unusual thing; usually you tell github or bitbucket or whatever it is to pull from upstream, but instead you pulled locally and directly. So now you've got two remotes and git will comment on this situation. If you don't like that, you can remove the upstream remote. I presume you've merged into your master and so up to origin so you don't need the upstream remote branch hanging around any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have seen something like: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits`. But this time I am getting `upstream/master` ... why?

You set the upstream of your branch to `upstream/master`.  Every branch can have one upstream (or no upstream, if you like).  The `git status` command will compare reachable commits from the branch and its upstream, counting, and tell you if your branch is ahead, behind, or diverged based on these counts.

You only get one upstream (or no upstream) setting per branch.  Note that the word "upstream" here is *not* the same as the `upstream` *remote*, i.e., the fact that some branch has some upstream is not dependent on the fact that you have a remote named `upstream`.  (Git is very bad about using words confusingly like this.)

> But is there any specific reason [for being two ahead]?

`git pull` means *Run two Git commands: First, run `git fetch`. Then, run a second Git command of my choice, `git merge` or `git rebase`, using whatever you got when you ran the first Git command.*

In this case, you ran `git pull upstream master`, so this ran:

```
git fetch upstream
```

followed by (probably, unless you changed your settings)

```
git merge <something>
```

The <something> here is a little tricky to explain,<sup>1</sup> but `git merge` can, and in this case probably did, create a new commit.

To know exactly what happened, we would have to know:

- what was in each repository *before* the `git fetch`, which tells us
- what the `git fetch` did, which lets us determine
- what the `git merge` did.

I generally recommend that those new to Git *avoid* `git pull` and instead (1) learn what each of these commands (`git fetch`, `git merge`, and `git rebase`) does, then (2) use the commands individually and separately.  This can still be confusing and a bit difficult but you have a much better chance of understanding what is going on, if you do it this way.

Note that when you do this, you have the opportunity to insert some *third* Git command between the two.  For example, when you know how to interpret `git log` output, you can say: *I ran fetch, now I'd like to run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` to see what `git fetch` did.*

(Once you know what each command does and can predict everything, *then* it's safe, or at least safe-ish, to use the all-in-one convenience "fetch and then merge-or-rebase" `git pull`.  I still mostly don't: I like to run those extra `git log` commands, or some of them, based on what `git fetch` says.)

If you want to get rid of these merge commits, you can do this with `git reset` or with most varieties of `git rebase`.  But maybe you should just keep these merge commits—that might be best.  What to use, and when, is a matter of situation and also personal taste in some cases—there's no blanket always-right action here.  Git provides a lot of individual tools with which you can build your own solutions, but for the most part, isn't a solution itself.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git fetch` leaves, in a file in your Git repository named `FETCH_HEAD`, some trace information.  The pull command fishes this information back out and builds the `git merge` command from that.  Given the arguments `upstream` and `master`, the effect is much the same as if you had run `git merge upstream/master`, but there are some minor differences.